# My Apache2 server slow to serve some css and js files. Any idea why?

Tags: css, server, debian, apache2

I'm not sure if this is a server or programming problem. I searched for a similar problem, but coudn't find anything like this.

I have a server running Debian Buster, serving sites on Apache2.
This week, one of my sites turned veeery slow, taking more than 25 seconds to renderize a page that usually took between 2 and 4 seconds.

At first, I checked the PHP program, but it completes processing everything in less than 1 second, sometimes it takes 2 seconds.

As I have to place some menus depending on the size of the page, I save everything in a PHP variable, then decide if I add extra menus or not.
In the end, I "echo" the variable to the browser.

That said, after checking a lot, I found that:

1. when I open a page, it takes no time to process the html in PHP, and after writing it to the browser, the browser starts "waiting for www.mydomainname.tld" for 20+ seconds.
2. by running top, I see 2 or 3 Apache processes running at 100% CPU on the server during that time.
3. One of my css files is missing on the server. By replacing it, one of the Apache processes at 100% disappeared (probably ran and closed);
4. Another CSS file is in the server, but with that file called in the html page, the same (100% CPU running) problem appear. If I disable it in the html, everything is running quickly as expected. Renderize in the browser in less than 4 seconds top.

I know this is not easily reproducible, and for now I disabled that second CSS file, so my site is running, but it would be great if anyone could give me an idea on where should I look for this solution, if any?

I even checked the hard disk, the SMART flags seems OK. Didn't stop the server to check the disks yet.
I have a copy of this server in a virtualbox running the same system, and locally it is amazingly fast.
My worry is if there is any problem in my server that I should get some maintenance for?

Just to add: The server is an AMD octa core with 32GB of RAM and 3 TB x 2 disks in a RAID1 set, so the server specs is not a culprit (I think)

Comment: This could be caused by a large number of factors, from heat to something in the php.ini file to an almost full disk to failing hardware. Is there anything in the Apache or system logs that might state there is a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matigo.

As I stated in the question, the server was working well (mostly), just had this slowness.

I requested a disk replacement and it looks like the problema was solved. I have to admit, it was a very long shot, sinde I didn't even know ehich disk to replace.

I even ran a badblocks check (had to take the server offline for that) and found no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a badblocks check in the RAID, and found no errors.
Then I asked the support staff to replace the older disk by its manufacturing date and surprisingly (since I had no proof of damage to that disk) they accepted.
After rebuilding the RAID set, the slowness disappeared somehow.

So, this is not a good answer, but may serve as a hint for anyone having this problem, too.